# Why does my term show up as undefined in python?

Tags: python, undefined

```
    unencryptionKey = (-16)


# Caesar Cypher Encryption
def passwordunEncrypt(encryptedMessage, key):

    # We will start with an empty string as our encryptedMessage
    encryptedMessage = ''


# For each symbol in the unencryptedMessage we will add an encrypted symbol into the encryptedMessage
for symbol in 'encryptedMessage':
    if symbol.isalpha():
        num = ord(symbol)
        num += unencryptionKey
```

When I run the above code it tells me that, in the last line, 'unencryptionKey' is undefined.  In the first line it shows exactly what 'unencryptionKey' is.  Why the error?  In the original code the term in the last line was just 'key' so I changed it as I assume they mean unencryptionKey is to be used and thought tying it to the first line would allow it to run. I tried to screenshot so the line numbers would be included but it didn't work so had to cut and paste.

Comment: unencryptionKey is indented, is it part of some other function? if so it's not accessible so undefined

Comment: `    unencryptionKey = (-16)` what is this white space? is there a part of code you arent showing us? because it seems like you defined `unencryptionKey ` in another scope so its gone in your loop

Comment: Possible duplicate: [short-description-of-the-scoping-rules](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/291978/short-description-of-the-scoping-rules)

Comment: The program is fairly long so I did not include all of it.  The problem now is that the previous issue is solved but when selecting other options in the program I have some new problems.  It looked to me like everything was properly defined but I am new to this.  I'm not sure the best way to provide all code without having a huge post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it seems like `unencryptionKey` defined not in global scope but in some function. remove the spaces before `unencryptionKey`, it should be on the same level as `def passwordunEncrypt`

Comment: I appreciate it.  That fixed the line in question.  The same term comes up with later in the code with the same error so I am guess it is a similar issue.  Is that error typically associated with improper spacing/tabs?

Comment: Python is sensitive to spaces and tabs
This is how you define the code block, seems like {} in c++ or js
Is that error typically associated with improper spacing/tabs? - it depends, probably you should learn how variable scopes work in Python
https://www.python-course.eu/python3_global_vs_local_variables.php